# MySql - Join, Sum, and return the Sums as columns

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySql query

```
SELECT purchases.client_id, purchases.credits_purchased
FROM purchases
JOIN  
(
   SELECT service_credit_id, SUM(if(checked_in = 1, 1, 0)) as used,
          SUM(if(checked_in = 0, 1, 0)) as scheduled
   FROM reservations GROUP BY service_credit_id
) reservations
ON reservations.service_credit_id = purchases.id
AND purchases.credits_purchased > reservations.used
WHERE purchases.client_id = 1
```

I'm using it to calculate if a client has any credits remaining to use.  Basically, clients buy quantities of credits, they can be scheduled as reservation and once they arrive they are checked in.

I would like to alter the above query to also return the used and scheduled columns.

I'd also like to convert this to Laravel's query builder if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe there are a lot of possible answers to the question, but a working solution was found fairly quickly.  I don't think the accepted answer was too long. It's a shame that people are so quick to close questions like this when clearly useful responses are forthcoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do that by simply adding those columns to the select like so :

```
SELECT purchases.client_id, purchases.credits_purchased, reservations.used, reservations.scheduled
FROM purchases
JOIN  
(
   SELECT service_credit_id, SUM(if(checked_in = 1, 1, 0)) as used,
      SUM(if(checked_in = 0, 1, 0)) as scheduled
   FROM reservations GROUP BY service_credit_id
) reservations
ON reservations.service_credit_id = purchases.id
AND purchases.credits_purchased > reservations.used
WHERE purchases.client_id = 1
```

Try this out in your Laravel app (`Query Builder`):

```
DB::table('purchases')->select(DB::raw('purchases.client_id,  purchases.credits_purchased, reservations.used, reservations.scheduled'))->
join(DB::raw('(
SELECT service_credit_id, SUM(if(checked_in = 1, 1, 0)) as used,
      SUM(if(checked_in = 0, 1, 0)) as scheduled
FROM reservations GROUP BY service_credit_id
) reservations'), function($join){
    $join->on('reservations.service_credit_id', '=', 'purchases.id');
    $join->on('purchases.credits_purchased','>', 'reservations.used');
})->where('purchases.client_id', 1)->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, that was too easy for me to figure out on my own!  I'll accept your answer in a few minutes once it's eligible to be accepted.

Comment: @Joshua now I'm trying to convert it to Laravel's Query Builder :P

Comment: that would be awesome.  Thank you.

Comment: @Joshua I made something that you can try, I'm not sure it will run though, it's a bit messy with two DB:raw but that's all I can think of right now, please try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change the fields to `SELECT purchases.client_id, purchases.credits_purchased, reservations.used, reservations.scheduled`